# changing device and browser toolbar colors

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, mobile

The Pinterest mobile site changes my browser toolbar and my nexus 5 toolbar to red.  How did do it? especially the device's styles?  I searched and only found sources for changing scrollbar  colors, which I'm not interested in.

Comment: I think that is because material design

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an answer to your question:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android